# why there is giving can not find symbol in LocalDate and Month classes

Tags: java, localdate, monthcalendar

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;

public class Birthday{
   public static void main(String args[]) {

    // declare variables for birthday
    int birthDate = 23;
    Month birthMonth = Month.SEPTEMBER;

    // get current date
    LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
    System.out.println("Todays Date: " + currentDate);

    // get current date and month
    int date = currentDate.getDayOfMonth();
    Month month = currentDate.getMonth();

    if(date == birthDate && month == birthMonth) {
      System.out.println("HAPPY BIRTHDAY TO YOU !!");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Today is not my birthday.");
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Comment: Please paste the exact text of the error message into your question.

Comment: Fix your code formatting. Either indent all by four spaces, or wrap in a pair of triple back-ticks.

Comment: `LocalDate` and `Month` are available starting with Java 8, probably used Java is older

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs successfully. See the [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/yhGMMV).

## Java 8+

Since you gave few details, I will guess that your problem is due to using a very old version of Java.

The *java.time* classes are **built into Java 8** and later, and Android 26+.

- If using **Java 6 or 7**, get most of the *java.time* functionality by adding the [ThreeTen-Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library to your Java project.
- If using **earlier Android**, the latest tooling provides most of the *java.time* functionality via “API desugaring”.

I will go on to mention a couple of other issues in your code.

## `Enum#equals`

You should replace the use of `==` with object references such as [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) objects. While that technically works with enum objects, using `==` on objects is a bad habit, with no benefit gained over calling [`Enum#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

```
if( date == birthDate && month.equals( birthMonth ) ) {
```

## `MonthDay`

Make a briefer version using [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html).

```
MonthDay currentMonthDay = MonthDay.now() ;
MonthDay birthMonthDay = MonthDay.of( Month.SEPTEMBER , 23 ) ;
if( currentMonthDay.equals( birthMonthDay ) ) {…}
```

Or a one-liner:

```
if( MonthDay.now().equals( MonthDay.of( Month.SEPTEMBER , 23 ) ) ) { … }
```

Comment: `Month` is an `enum`. It can be compared with `==`.

Comment: @gmanjon I added a note about that being a bad habit, not technically incorrect. Thank you for the prompt.